# Efficient way to scan lines read from file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have the need to scan words from lines, which are read directly from a text file. I'm currently using BufferedReader, FileReader and Scanner for that.
The thing goes like follows:

```
while((thisLine = reader.readLine()) != null){

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(thisLine);

            while(scan.hasNext()){
                thisLine = scan.next();
                System.out.println(thisLine);
            }
}
```

It works fine, but I was wondering if there's a more efficient way to do so, without instantiating the Scanner class in every line being read.

EDIT: I actually belive I need to use the Scanner class, since I have to, again, "scan" a line if it encounters a certain pattern. I'm working in an assembler for SIC machine, so I have to find out whether the thing I'm reading is a comment, a directive, operand, etc.

Comment: Check out my answer I use scanner and I don't instantiate it each time

Answer (score 1):

[java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8)

If you're using Java 8, you may want to use this simple way to read through a File.

```
try(Stream<String> s = Files.lines(Paths.get("myFileName.txt"))) {
     s.flatMap(x -> Arrays.stream(x.split(" ")))
      .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

---

### Output

[image: test]

[image]

Comment: Your example suffers from a very serious bug: you never close the stream! Streams based on files, network or other special resources have to be closed!

Comment: @SvetlinZarev Better?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `Scanner` at all. Remove the entire while loop and just print the value of `thisLine`

```
while((thisLine = reader.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(thisLine);
}
```

Comment: I actually need it to scan through the line if it ever encounters certain pattern, and, as far as I'm concerned, Scanner class can achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want each word on a new line, you can *eliminate* the `Scanner` and use `String.split("\\s+")` to tokenize each line into words by white-space. Then, assuming you're using Java 8+, you should be able to use a lambda to iterate the tokens. Something like

```
while ((thisLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    Stream.of(thisLine.split("\\s+")).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `Arrays#stream` be more efficient here?